# Python Telnetlib - Enters password before password input asked

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, telnet, telnetlib

I am new to python.I am trying to connect to telnet,then login using the username and password and execute command and grep the results one by one.I have coded as below :

```
print ("Starting Client...")
host    = "<myIp>"
timeout = 120
user = "myUserName"
password = "myPassword"

print ("Connecting...")
try:
    session = telnetlib.Telnet(host, 23, timeout)
    session.read_until("USERNAME : ",2)
    session.write(user + "\n")
    print("UserName entered")
    response = session.read_until("PASSWORD : ",2)
    print(str(response))
    session.write(password + "\n")
    print("password Entered")
except Exception,e:
    print ("socket timeout")
else:
    print("Sending Commands...")
    session.write("Mycommand".encode('ascii') + b"\r")
    print("Reading...")
    output = session.read_until("commandBash>", timeout )
    session.close()
    print(output)
    print("Done")
```

For the above program i get my output as :

```
Starting Client...
Connecting...
UserName entered
 myUserName
password Entered
Sending Commands...
Reading...
myPasswordMycommand

PASSWORD:
Done
```

From this i could know that password hasnt been even entered when it asks for password.It actually enters password and command before password is prompted.So i even tried putting time.sleep(20) after username entered.Still no use.I couldnt figure out what i am missing here.Please help me out friends

Answer (score 1):

Found out what i was missing.Its very small thing .I missed putting this code to do "ENTER" opereation below every session.write.The code i missed was session.write("\r") where "\r" means ENTER operation